# Permissions To Read Windows File Across Network in NodeJS

Tags: windows, macos, node.js

I'm trying to read a text file using NodeJS on a Mac. The file is on a Windows computer which is on the same network.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = "smb://someserver/stuff/names.txt";

fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

When I run this code, I get:

```
> Error: ENOENT, open 'smb://someserver/stuff/names.txt'
```

I probably need to authenticate access to the file, but I haven't found any docs or modules that deal with this scenario. Is it possible to read/write files like this?

#### Update (10/22)

I've tried using UNC paths (ie `\\someserver\stuff\names.txt`) but I believe that is only part of the solution. Somehow I need to supply username/password/domain because this file requires special permission. Is it possible to supply permissions somehow? For example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = '\\someserver\stuff\names.txt';
var credentials = { username:'mydomain/jsmith', password:'password' }; ???

fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: It seems that your question is really old and with no conclusive answer. Did you acheive this, and if so, how? I am scratching my head with this one. I could, of course, invoke DOS commands to achieve this, but surely there is a better way?

Comment: Trying to achieve essentially the same thing (from NodeJS running on Ubuntu, however) - but to access with read/write access a Windows file share. Not seeing a good solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [UNC paths](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsnetworking/g/unc-name.htm) if you are trying to access resources from other network drives.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = "\\someserver\stuff\names.txt";

fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: the above code snippet. fs isn't using the credentials of service account or user. Can you pls share a snipper where fs uses the credentials.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use the 'node-cmd' to update the credentials** first and then try to read/write to the folder using the unc path.

```
var cmd = require("node-cmd");
const data = cmd.runSync(
  "net use \\IP /user:username password"
);

// Now you do read / write using the fs
fs.readdir("\\IP")
```

Comment: I like this idea, but i think `fs.readdir("\\IP")` should be executed under the `cmd` scope to work. Have you tried your solution ?

Comment: Yes, It worked for me without any issues!

Comment: @AkshayKumar:In the above code snippet. fs isn't using the cmd or the credentials. Can you pls share a snipper where fs uses the credentials.