Why NodeJS fs module won't read or write to visible folder shared on the network?
I'm scaling my NodeJS app (on Windows 11) and need to setup additional workstations (Windows 11 aswell).
Right now I simply need a shared folder, so I created one and made it visible on the network. It works and I'm able to edit its content files from both the physical hoster as well as any computer on the network, using Windows tools like text editor etc. I see changes in real time so it seems to work fine.
Problems arise when I try to do the same programmatically. A simple fs.writeFileSync("//DESKTOP-COOLNAME/folder/test.txt", "Hello, World!", "utf8") will work on the hoster machine (or if I use the real absolute path) but on any secondary device on the network, I get :
node:fs:2342
    return binding.writeFileUtf8(
                   ^

Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open '//DESKTOP-COOLNAME/folder/test.txt'
    at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2342:20)
    at file:///C:/Users/me/some_folder/some_file.js:3:4
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:222:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:323:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:28:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:113:12) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '\\\\DESKTOP-COOLNAME\\folder\\test.txt'
}

Node.js v20.12.0


See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166614/permissions-to-read-windows-file-across-network-in-nodejs

Thank you I was actually investigating a way to pass credentials since they were required when accessing the folder for the first time from the Windows GUI.

import cmd from "node-cmd"; cmd.runSync(\net use \DESKTOP-${device} /user:${username} ${password}`);` do actually compile when the right credentials are used but any consecutive fs function call will still fail with the same unknown error.
